# Run function from Button or URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4.2

I have the following test function, that I want to call directly from my URL or by clicking a link from my blade view.

```
public function callMeDirectlyFromUrl()
{
    return "I have been called from URL :)";
}
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to call a function directly from button-click or URL link from the blade view in Laravel?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Eloquent to make these queries?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Here is the solution:

We assume you have a function `callMeDirectlyFromUrl` in `YourController`, here is how you can call the function directly from a URL, Hyperlink, or Button.

**Create Route**

```
Route::get('/pagelink', 'YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl');
```

**Add link in the view blade php file**

```
<a href="{{action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl')}}">Link name/Embedded Button</a>
```

This has been tested on Laravel 4.2 -> 5.2 so far.

By clicking on this link or calling the URL `www.somedomain.com/pagelink` the function will be executed directly.

Comment: How would get get back to the original page, after being directed to the "/pagelink" ?

Comment: I have not maintained my laravel skills for while, doing more .net. But what out digging deep in your question this can be done 2 or more ways, one simple way in javascript (window.history.back();) or in php/laravel, in your controller you can get current url some thing like "$request->path()", and cache is as key value, than you can fetch the key value and use it as return url.