# How to have a dynamic controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to call dynamic popup views in which I need to pass the data through the controller, I want the controller to be dynamic which will access the particular function and make the view accordingly. Basically i'm looking for something like this:

```
Route::post('/popup/{id}', 'PopupController@{$id}');
```

So basically suppose when it is called like this: `mydomain.com/popup/id1`, it should call `PopupController@id1`.

Help me out with this.

Comment: try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322854/run-function-from-button-or-url-in-laravel with bit modification and it could be used

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ it will be too lengthy, as I have repetitive links or buttons.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question about requirement, since it is not clear about lengthy thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a method that will fire the appropriate function

```
Route::post('/popup/{id}', 'PopupController@dispatch');
```

In PopupController

```
public function dispatch($id)
{
    return $this->$id()
}
```

then if your `$id` is `someFunction` you need to make sure your controller has `function someFunction()` method

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest instead of writing a dynamic route or controller use switch case in controller action.

e.g.

```
Route::post('/popup/{id}', 'PopupController@action');
```

In Controller

```
public function action($id)
{
  switch($id)
  {
     case 1: ...

     case 2: ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I can use this, but I'm collecting data from dom element and making the view, each switch case will be too lengthy and messy for me.

Comment: I prefer that using dynamic call instead of writing each possibilities exhaustively in order to prevent adding cases manually in the future.